# Intuition/Simple Proofs required about $kernel$, $rank$, $co-rank$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, intuition, matrix-rank

This question might be so elementary , but I love to see some geometric/algebraic approach for these facts concerning transpose matrix. I know some basic thing about DUAL space but those are not satisfying in the way I know.

$1. \: rank (A)=rank(A^t)$

$2. \: ker (A) = co-image(A^t)$

$3. \: co-ker(A)= image(A^t)$

---

P.S. One may re-state the third fact as

$$Ax=0 , x^ty=0 \implies \exists z: A^tz=y$$

Is there any simple way just using basic algebra to prove the fact?

Thanks community

Comment: $Ax=0$ iff $x^tA^t=0$ and thus $ker(A)=im(A^t)^{\perp}$, what is $co$?